# iOS) How to add a divider(==separator) between tabbarItems

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitabbar, tabbar, uitabbaritem

I searched this question many times but couldn't get enough information.

So I will use UIButton or UIView to replace UITabbar for customizing issue.

I want to put divider(separator) between two tabbarItems and bottom lines like the image below[image]

But What I made now is below:
[image]

How can I make it as I want?
I did customize many view components(UIViewcontroller, UIButton, UITextfiled,UITableViewCell,UICollectionViewCell) but I don't know how to customize tabbarItem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid there is no specific option to set a divider in UITabBar. But you can always use a custom tab bar. You can check this out, it has a special property for seperator image:

[NMBottomTabBarController for iOS](https://github.com/priankaliz/NMBottomTabBarController)

There is also another option. You may like this :) I also used it myself in one of my app. I made an image that looks like a tab bar with seperator as a background image. Then put the items on it. Easy peasy. For example check this image:

[Image Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HnnvO.png)

I hope this helps.

Comment: May I see your customizing tabbar using that option?

Comment: This is how it looks with background image http://i.stack.imgur.com/gl7Fe.png

You can use different shape and color background images for sure.